# How can I quickly play the selected song in iTunes, without playing the rest of the album?

Tags: itunes

When no music is playing and when a song in album view is selected, how can I quickly play this song, but only this song, and not the following songs in the album?

I found out you could use Up Next via the context menu (right click), but that takes two mouse clicks and after that you manually need to press play to start playing. Is there a faster way to do this (preferably using a shortcut)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to save this script to `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/iTunes/` in AppleScript Editor and give it a shortcut with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

```
try
    tell application "iTunes"
        play item 1 of selection with once
    end tell
end try
```

Without the try block there would be an error dialog if for example the selection was empty.