# How to just play one song in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

*iTunes Version 12.9.5.5*

If I click the "play" arrow on the song below, iTunes will add *every* song in the album below it to the current playlist. That's **not** what I want. I just want to hear the song I selected.

How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: @IconDaemon – no CD; this is the "album view" in iTunes. The album was released on 2 "discs" originally but the actual mp3 files in in my iTunes library. The unwanted behavior I describe above occurs with every album.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74120/how-can-i-quickly-play-the-selected-song-in-itunes-without-playing-the-rest-of?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Following assumes that:

- you want to listen to one song in your library
- you know the name of the song (or part of it)
- Spotlight is indexing your music (by default it's enabled)

Invoke Spotlight, enter song name, select it from suggestions (it may already be selected by default), press enter and listen this one song (in Big Sur it's Music, but it should work in similar fashion with earlier versions with iTunes as well).

Scenario using keyboard:

- ⌘+Space (to open Spotlight search)
- enter song name (like 'Wasted Words')
- music file should be displayed in results (maybe even selected as default)
- file selected press Enter (starts playing song)

If there are too many files found one can narrow search by adding `kind:music` right after song name. It is also useful then one remembers only one or more words from song name. Just enter word(s) and narrow results down with kind (like `Words kind:music`)